# C#: Multiply an array elements with each other

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to be able to multiply all members of a given numeric array with each other.

So for example for an array like: `[1,2,3,4]`, I would like to get the product of `1*2*3*4`.

I have tried this but didn't work:

```
/// <summary>
/// Multiplies numbers and returns the product as rounded to the nearest 2 decimal places.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="decimals"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static decimal MultiplyDecimals(params decimal[] decimals)
{
   decimal product = 0;

   foreach (var @decimal in decimals)
   {
       product *= @decimal;
   }

   decimal roundProduct = Math.Round(product, 2);
   return roundProduct;
}
```

I am sorry I know this must be simple!

Thanks.

Comment: You're starting with a value of 0. What usually happens when you multiply something by 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another opportunity to show off the power of LINQ:

```
public static decimal MultiplyDecimals(params decimal[] decimals)
{
    return decimals.Aggregate(1m, (p, d) => p * d);
}
```

This

- starts with an initial value of `1` (the `m` modifier statically types the constant as `decimal`) and then
- iteratively multiplies all the values.

EDIT: Here a variant that includes rounding. I've omitted it, because I don't think it's required (you don't have floating-point problems with `decimal`), but here it is for completeness:

```
public static decimal MultiplyDecimals(params decimal[] decimals)
{
    return Math.Round(decimals.Aggregate(1m, (p, d) => p * d), 2);
}
```

Comment: I like LINQ approach but you need to add rounding

Comment: @Heinzi Oh yeah, sorry. I totally forgot about that. Please ignore my comment, then :-)

Answer (score 2):

check this;

```
public static decimal MultiplyDecimals(params decimal[] decimals)
{
    decimal product = 1; // here is difference!

    foreach (var @decimal in decimals)
    {
        product *= @decimal;
    }
    decimal roundProduct = Math.Round(product, 2);
    return roundProduct;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the value of the product decimal to 1 or higher because x * 0 everytime is 0

-->    `decimal product = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
decimal product = 0;
```

to this :

```
decimal product = 1;
```

You started multiplying by 0 that's why.